# 'lint_control_architecture_valid_contents' error

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap

I was creating a framework app, cURL for Snappy. I could create and publish it, but the published app raised a few errors.

2 Fails:

- `found binaries for architecture 'all': bin/curl lint_control_architecture_valid_contents`
- `(MANUAL REVIEW) type 'framework' not allowed lint_snappy_type_redflag` What does this mean?

2 Warnings:

- `security policy not found framework_policies`
- `unknown entries in package.yaml: 'description,summary' lint_snappy_unknown`

How can I fix it?

- [App page](https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/click-apps/3701/review/seq/2/)
- [Github issue](https://github.com/tetor/snappy-curl/issues/3)

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually several questions here.

```
found binaries for architecture 'all': bin/curl lint_control_architecture_valid_contents
```

This means that you have included compiled binaries in the package (in this case `bin/curl`) but said that the package is architecture-independent in the package manifest (not specifying an `architectures` key in `meta/package.yaml` means it defaults to `architectures: ["all"]`, resulting in `Architecture: all` in `DEBIAN/control`).  You should update `meta/package.yaml` to include `architectures: ["amd64"]`.

```
unknown entries in package.yaml: 'description,summary' lint_snappy_unknown
```

You have included properties in your `meta/package.yaml` that are not recognised, namely `description` and `summary`. You should remove those.

See [the guide on package metadata](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/guides/package-metadata/) for more details on what properties are allowed.

```
(MANUAL REVIEW) type 'framework' not allowed lint_snappy_type_redflag
```

and

```
security policy not found framework_policies
```

The [link](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/guides/frameworks/) after the failure message tells you what you need to know here:

> - Frameworks must always specify framework policy, otherwise the store will reject it
> - Framework snaps will always trigger a manual review to ensure the framework policy has not changed. Alternatively, the first upload could require manual review, but subsequent uploads could be automatically approved if the security policy does not change

Comment: Many thanks for awesome answer !

I wanted fix it but AppArmor and Seccomp settings are too difficult for me. I published again but change type to app from framework.

https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/click-apps/3701/

However, app type's command name was **curl.curl** not **curl** . It was not good. So I'll try create security setting and remake cURL for snappy as framework type.

Thanks!!